# 3rd quartile value using R

Tags: r

I have a problem with the 3rd quartile value of these data:

```
tj<-c(0 ,      0    ,      0    ,      0    ,      0    ,      0    ,      0    ,      0    ,
      0 ,      0    ,      0    ,      0    ,      0    ,      0    ,      0    ,      1    ,
      1 ,      1    ,      1    ,      1    ,      1    ,      1    ,      2    ,      2    ,
      2 ,      2    ,      2    ,      2    ,      2    ,      2    ,      2    ,      2    ,
      2 ,      2    ,      3    ,      3    ,      3    ,      3    ,      3    ,      4    ,
      4 ,      4    ,      5    ,      5    ,      5    ,      5    ,      6    ,      6    ,
      6 ,      6    ,      7    ,      8    ,      8    ,      9    ,      16   ,      20   )
```

If I calculate it by myself I obtain 4.5 (4+5/2)
If I use R I get 4.25

```
summary(tj)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   0.000   2.000   3.036   4.250  20.000  


res<-quantile(tj, probs = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1))
res
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
 0.00  0.00  2.00  4.25 20.00
```

I don't understand why R calculates it in a different way and what is the correct 3rd quartile value.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are up to 9 different algorithms for estimating quantiles. From the [R helpfile](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/quantile) you can read all of them. In your case, you can use `type=2`

```
> quantile(tj, probs = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), type=2)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
 0.0  0.0  2.0  4.5 20.0
```